# Angular *ngFor not getting previous elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, socket.io, rxjs

I am using socket.io in my angular and node application. A user joins the room the user can see his username in the user list. When user2 joins, user1 can see both user1 and user2 in the user list. However, user2 can only see user2. If user 3 joins. user1 can see user 1, user2, and user3. User2 can see user2 and user3. However, user3 only sees user3.

**chat.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable, onErrorResumeNext, observable } from 'rxjs';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()

export class ChatService {
  private socket = io('http://localhost:8080');

  joinRoom(data) {
    this.socket.emit('join', data);
  }


  newUserJoined() {
    let observable = new Observable<{user: String, message:String}>(observer => {
      this.socket.on('new user joined ', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };
    });
    return observable;
  }

  leaveRoom(data) {
    this.socket.emit('leave', data);
  }

  userLeftRoom() {
    let observable = new Observable<{user: String, message:String}>(observer => {
      this.socket.on('left room', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };
    });
    return observable;
  }

  sendMessage(data) {
    this.socket.emit('message', data);
  }

  newMessageRecieved() {
    let observable = new Observable<{user: String, message:String, time: any}>(observer => {
      this.socket.on('new message', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };
    });
    return observable;
  }


  getRoomUsers() {
    let observable = new Observable<{user: String, message:String}>(observer => {
      this.socket.on('roomUsers', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };
    });
    return observable;
  }
}
```

**chat.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChatService } from '../../services/chat.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css'],
  providers: [ChatService]
})


export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {

  room: any;
  user: any;
  username: any;
  roomName: any;
  messageArray: Array<{user: String, message: String, time: any}> = [];
  userArray: Array<{user: String, message: String}> = [];
  messageText: String;
  time: any;


  constructor( private chatService: ChatService,  private authService: AuthService) {

    // this.chatService.newUserJoined()
    // .subscribe(data => this.userArray.push(data));

    // this.chatService.userLeftRoom()
    // .subscribe(data => this.userArray.splice(this.userArray.indexOf(data)));

    this.chatService.newMessageRecieved()
    .subscribe(data => this.messageArray.push(data));

    this.chatService.getRoomUsers()
    .subscribe(data => this.userArray.push(data));

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser() {
    this.user = localStorage.getItem('user');
    this.username = JSON.parse(this.user).username;
    this.getRoom();
  }

  getRoom() {
    this.room = localStorage.getItem('room');
    this.roomName = JSON.parse(this.room).name;
    this.join();
  }

  join() {
    console.log(this.roomName);
    console.log(this.username);
    this.chatService.joinRoom({user: this.username, room: this.roomName});
  }


  leave() {
    console.log(this.roomName);
    console.log(this.username);
    let userIndex = this.userArray.indexOf(this.username);
    delete this.userArray[userIndex];
    localStorage.removeItem('room');
    this.chatService.leaveRoom({user: this.username, room: this.roomName});
  }

  sendMessage() {
    console.log(this.roomName);
    console.log(this.username);
    this.chatService.sendMessage({user: this.username, room: this.roomName, message: this.messageText, time: this.time});
    this.messageText = '';
  }

}
```

**chat.component.html**

```
 <ul *ngFor="let item of userArray" id="usersList">
          <li >{{item.user}}</li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: in your userArray, are the other users there?

Comment: In the user1's chatroom page he can see all other users

Comment: what is your question ? it's not really clear

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID I am sorry. My questions is, how can I get user2 to show that user1 is in the chatroom? It only shows the users in the userList that join after the user not before.

Answer (score 0):

What comes through the “roomUsers” socket event? All the current users?

To me it looks like that event is only dispatching new arrivals, so every user that shows up only sees themselves and users that come after them.

Without too much knowledge of your code, it seems like one solution is to make the “roomUsers” event contain all users and not just newly added users. Another possibility is to define that Observable outside of the function and then provide the *same* observable to each newcomer, so everyone has the same data.  Switch that function to a stream and expose it something like:

roomUsers$ = from(this.socket.on(“roomUsers”).pipe(
scan((a,c) => [...a, c], []),
shareReplay(1));

The shareReplay(1) operator means even late subscribers get the most recent value, and the scan builds things up as an array. So on your component you wouldn’t do the .push method into the array.

Again, I could be missing context, but hopefully this points you in the right directions.